# Why is Z3 throwing a 'sort mismatch' exception here?

Tags: z3, z3py

I have the following code:

```
from z3       import *
x= Bool('x')
State, (A,B) = EnumSort('State',['A', 'B'])
s = Const('s', State)
#s = Int('s')
vars = [s,x]
if x in vars:
    print('yes')
```

when I run it I get an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cygdrive/c/temp/testSorts.py", line 9, in <module>
    if x in vars:
  File "/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/z3-4.8.12-x64-win/bin/python/z3/z3.py", line 1012, in __eq__
    a, b = _coerce_exprs(self, other)
  File "/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/z3-4.8.12-x64-win/bin/python/z3/z3.py", line 1186, in _coerce_exprs
    s = _coerce_expr_merge(s, b)
  File "/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/z3-4.8.12-x64-win/bin/python/z3/z3.py", line 1171, in _coerce_expr_merge
    _z3_assert(False, "sort mismatch")
  File "/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/z3-4.8.12-x64-win/bin/python/z3/z3.py", line 112, in _z3_assert
    raise Z3Exception(msg)
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: sort mismatch
```

If I change the type of the variable `s` from my own sort to a standard one, say `Int` then everything's fine.

Could someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the rather "weakly" typed nature of z3-bindings for Python.

SMTLib (and hence z3) is a strongly-typed language: Every variable has a given sort, and it is illegal to even compare two variables that don't have the same sort. (i.e., it's a type error.)

For various (both historical and technical) reasons, Python API blurs the boundaries of types: It tries to cast them as appropriate to make things work, to follow the Python philosophy of untyped programming. Unfortunately, this is one of those cases where it doesn't work, and the outcome is utterly confusing: When you compare an `Int` and a `Bool`, there's an internal check to return false; but there isn't such a check when you have an enumerated type. Hence the error you're getting.

So, how do you program when you need such checks? Always check the sort first. So, you should code that `if`-statement as:

```py
for v in vars:
    if (x.sort() == v.sort()) and (x == v):
        print('yes')
```

You'll see that this version works correctly regardless whether `s` is an enumeration sort, or `Bool`, or some other type. It's more verbose than what you wrote, but it's the only way to code such things without falling to the traps of weakly-typed nature of the python API for z3.

Comment: Ok fair enough, but its somewhat confusing to an end user if certain sorts have that check and others don't. I have the "in" test in many places in the code, and everything worked fine until I defined my own sort, and unfortunately Python won't let you define your own operators. Any chance of fixing this?

Comment: You can file a request at the z3 issue tracker (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues)  but I very much doubt this is something they'll work on. There has been prior issues where such "castings" were not only confusing but rather buggy, you can search stack-overflow for related questions. I'm afraid the ship has sailed on this one.

Comment: Is "String" not an internal sort either? I get the original error even if I use String in place of my own sort in the original code ie I do `s = String('s')`

Comment: `String` is internal, but coercing is only done haphazardly, and only allows Strings and Sequences to be "compatible" in this sense. See https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/50717fb655eda6c4c297d2947adf79a7387e4f1b/src/api/python/z3/z3.py#L1220-L1238